# Rest Endpoint which handles "curl...-data"

Tags: spring, forms, rest

I have an api, which should be usable like: 
curl 'http://localhost:8080/api/bla' --data '{"comment":"something"}'.

I have therefore created a post endpoint like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bla", produces = { "application/json" },       
                method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Token> getBla(@RequestParam  String comment){}
```

but I get an error **Required String parameter 'comment' is not present**
I also tried to add

```
@RequestParam(value="comment", required=true) String comment
```

with the same error. 
Can you please help me to tell what's the problem here?

Comment: `--data "comment=something"`. That's how you would do it if you are going to use `@RequestParam`. If you want to use JSON, that's a whole different story.

Comment: Ah - Ok, thank you for your answer - so the format is the problem. Can you please show me an example how to do implement my endpoint to be able to send the upper json format with curl? This would help me a lot, thank you

Comment: Use a POJO to map the JSON properties on the server side method parameter and use `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'` with cURL.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I found out the endpoint could be both json and plain string...